# How to add CSS to change colour on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button with text inside. I want it so that when you hover over the box, the color of the box changes to white, and the colour of the text changes to blue.

How can I add css to make my text and box change colors on hover?

Edited: I got the html snippet for that from another part of the website template I am editing. It is basically a box that does exactly what I have outline above. I then placed it inside the list tag of the menu html, hoping that it will just transfer the functionality but it didn't work. So I tried to add the [hover:] but it still isn't working.

I know I am doing something wrong but I don't know enough to know what it is.

Code snippet is for html:

Upload resources

Comment: I won't downvote, but most users would ask you to show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `:hover` pseudo selector

e.g.

```
button {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
}

button:hover {
    color: blue;
    background: white;
}
```

Of course, replace with the actual hex codes you need rather than the colour names above, and any valid property can be used, e.g. `border`, `text-decoration` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question above.

Comment: if you are able to, posting an example of the html you want to apply styles to would help to create an exact answer that you need.

Comment: I already did but let me put it here directly:

Answer (score 1):

Use `:hover` pseudo selector

```
element{
    color: white;
    background: blue;
}

element:hover{
    color: blue;
    background: white;
}
```

You can check these at [Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

Comment: Your code example doesn't have a `:hover` pseudo selector.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question above.